# DataTable Select(String) Function Help VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

I made a datatable with 2 columns a transactionTime column and a numberOfTransactions column. I made the table with the pre-defined transaction times and want to add the number of transactions from an XML file. I have gotten through the XML file and want to add the data to the correct row. Here is the function:

```
Function AddRow(ByVal timeOfTransaction As String, ByVal numberOfTransactions As String, ByRef dataTableOfTransactions As DataTable) As String


    Dim row() As DataRow = dataTableOfTransactions.Select("transactionTime = timeOfTransaction")

    If row(0) IsNot Nothing Then
        row(0)("numberOfTransactions") = numberOfTransactions

    End If
    Return Nothing

End Function
```

When I run this it overwrites the first element in the table's numberOfTransactions coloumn. I know it has to do with the "transactionTime = timeOfTransaction" part but I can't seem to get it to read timeOfTransaction as a reference to a string instead of a literal. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write something like this :

```
Dim row() As DataRow = dataTableOfTransactions.Select("transactionTime=#" & timeOfTransaction & "#")
```

But be careful with your date/month or month/date format, it depends of your regional settings.

Comment: timeOfTransation is a String not a Date though.

Answer (score 0):

```
row(0)("numberOfTransactions") = numberOfTransactions
```

Right there you are telling the program to overwrite that value with number of transactions.

If you want that value you need to set it to something, not set something to it.

Also, if you want your select to work properly try doing it like this

```
dataTableOfTransactions.Select("transactionTime = " + timeOfTransaction)
```

Comment: In the begining of the program, none of the numberOfTransactions columns are filled so I do want them to be overwritten the first time. Also I tried the select you suggested and it says "missing operand after 'With' operator. Thanks!